# Solving vector equations with dot products

Tags: computational-geometry, 3d

I'm working on a triangle-triangle intersection algorithm using [this](http://www.applet-magic.com/trintersection.htm) article ("The Line Intersection of Two Planes" part). The problem is that I don't know how to solve vector equations with dot products.

```
N1 . (X - Q1) = 0
N2 . (X - Q'1) = 0
X[2] = 0
```

I have vectors `N1, N2, Q1, Q'1` and the value of `X[2]` wich is `0`. How can i find the value of `X[0]` and `X[1]`?

Comment: Do you know how to solve systems of linear equations?

Comment: The usual discrete inner product is $A\cdot B$ = $\sum a_i b_i $, you can substitute to get scalar equations...

Comment: This is a problem well-suited to projective geometry.  Is that an approach you'd consider instead?  The solutions to such problems in projective space are known (you would not have to solve a system of equations, merely evaluate the answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As ido described in a comment, you the easiest way is to expand the dot product.

Suppose that $N1=[N_{11},N_{12},N_{13}]$ and $N2=[N_{21},N_{22},N_{23}]$, as well as similar representations for $Q1$ and $Q'1$. The equations can then be written in the form:
$$
\begin{align}
N_{11}(x_0-Q_{11})+N_{12}(x_1-Q_{12})+N_{13}(x_2-Q_{13})&=0\\
N_{21}(x_0-Q'_{11})+N_{22}(x_1-Q'_{12})+N_{23}(x_2-Q'_{13})&=0\\
x_2&=0
\end{align}
$$
Now, using the third equation $x_2=0$ and substituting this into the first two equations, upon expanding the brackets produces:
$$
\begin{align}
N_{11}x_0+N_{12}x_1&=N_{11}Q_{11}+N_{12}Q_{12}+N_{13}Q_{13}\\
N_{21}x_0+N_{22}x_1&=N_{21}Q'_{11}+N_{22}Q'_{12}+N_{23}Q'_{13}\\
\end{align}
$$
This is a system of linear equations, which can be solved by any of the methods described [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations#Solving_a_linear_system). Using any of these techniques, you obtain the solution for this linear system as
$$
\begin{align}
x_0&={N_{22}\left(N_{11}Q_{11}+N_{12}Q_{12}+N_{13}Q_{13}\right)-N_{12}\left(N_{21}Q'_{11}+N_{22}Q'_{12}+N_{23}Q'_{13}\right) \over N_{11}N_{22}-N_{12}N_{21}},\\
x_1&={N_{11}\left(N_{21}Q'_{11}+N_{22}Q'_{12}+N_{23}Q'_{13}\right)-N_{21}\left(N_{11}Q_{11}+N_{12}Q_{12}+N_{13}Q_{13}\right) \over N_{11}N_{22}-N_{12}N_{21}}.
\end{align}
$$